# Old owner completed house addition with expired permit

Tags: building-regulations, permitting

Just bought new home in California.  We are planning to do some remodeling so was looking at the issued permits on the property.

In my research, it seems as though the old owner added 995 sq ft to the home ~ 5 years ago, but the permit on record shows as expired ( big “Expired” stamp on it.

My question is what is the implication for me? Do I need to be worried about this?  If so, what should I do?

Update: thanks for the comments - super helpful for me as I’m a first-time home buyer and navigating this for the first time.

Comment: You should be able to determine the dates of inspection of critical build steps (e.g. foundation, framing, sheathing, mechanical, electrical, plumbing). If all that was inspected and approved, and the permit expired prior to Final Inspection, then at least the "bones" are sound. Either way you are going to want to pull a permit and get a retroactive "Final", which may include expense for any final details that were n't completed. I assume this is an "as is" sale? Would likely have to be for unpermitted addition, use it to leverage down the price...

Comment: Does california have a sort of truth-in-sale declaration where the owner has to check a box saying all work was permitted and done to code or not?

Comment: Seller must *disclose* known un-permitted work and any other known serious defects, but can still sell.

Comment: Checking this detail **before** paying is a good idea, if you are considering going through with a purchase.

Comment: Seems to me this is more of a legal question than a DIY question.

Comment: Contact the county building codes division and ask them we don’t know if any inspections were completed or if the inspections failed and they just kept on working. It could be small issues on a final without that information it is not something we can answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not something we can answer without contacting building codes division.

Comment: OP asks "what should I do" and the comments here make for a good answer. The biggest (but not only) concern for me would be whether the addition complies with all setbacks & zoning. Was the plan approved and was the building inspected for that stage?

Comment: @p2000 -Building permits in CA are only issues if all the planning, plans, looks, setback, wiring diagram, structure integrity, appearance are approved.  Once approved, the building permit is issued.

Comment: @Programmer66 makes sense, but is that what he meant with "issued". Possibly. And was at least the foundation built in accordance with the specs? We don't know. This really requires auditing a paper trail of forms and invoices. It could be attempted here, but without continued clear and prompt input from the OP we can offer little help, and this is of little value to other readers.

Comment: Obviously the previous submitted the plan for approval but has not completed the application process due to some hanging issues, then went ahead and built the addition without the permit and required inspection. I guess the issues are rather minor, otherwise, the application/plan will be rejected, instead of stamping "expired". However, it is now your hot potato and you will have to decide whether to reapply and complete the process or live with it. Note the latter possess the risks as the addition could be found and ordered to be taken down, or a  headache at the next sale.

Comment: I think the best the OP can do is throw themselves at the mercy of the Permits people and hope for a sympathetic individual.

Comment: @r13 is right, the permit WAS issued and there were some prelim inspections done, but for some reason it was never closed out when the work was completed and then the permit expired.  Looks like I’ll need to go through the paper trail to figure out what issues blocked final inspection?

Comment: Good luck, pal. Expecting the worst, the previous owner could have deviated from the permit plan, a mistake deemed too difficult or cost too much to fix, which wouldn't be getting better now. I don't like litigation, but in this case, you might want to consult a lawyer who is familiar with real estate transactions, to find the remedy, if any.